# MSSNG VWLS CNNCT WLL

Tags: word, knowledge, connect-wall

The words and phrases in the following connect wall are missing their vowels. Insert the missing vowels into each word or phrase (all of the words/phrases are spaced correctly), then sort them into four groups of four each. Finally, use the group categories to find a **thematic one word answer.**

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JS N | MGNT | WK | RGN |
| MTR | ZR | RD | DY |
| FSTD | SCL | BRGR | PPLT |
| FNNC | PRST | JD | CTR |

**Hint 1:** (updated)

> `JS N` is a two word phrase that is a portion of a legal term.

**Hint 2:**

> If `JS N` is giving you trouble, you can replace it with `D`.

Comment: Nice challenge. [Here's a bit of context for anyone who's wondering what this is all about/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Only_Connect)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Glad that someone got the reference :D

Comment: Am I correct to assume Y is not considered a vowel (Because of DY)?

Comment: @Zimonze Yes, Y is not a vowel, the only missing letters are AEIOU

Comment: Is the space between "JS N" significant? Because on the wikipedia page, "VR NNGDLT TL" was solved as "Vernon God Little".

Comment: @JS1 The space is intentional. I should’ve mentioned that, unlike the show, all the words and phrases here are spaced correctly, so you only need to worry about the vowels

Comment: Love Only Connect and love this concept, but dang is it proving tricky! Pretty confident I have two groups but will keep working on it... Will post a partial at the end of the day (after tonight's episode!) if nobody has made more progress in the meantime :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer in the style of the question... TH SXTN WRDS/PHRSS N TH CNNCT WLL CLD B CTGRSD LK THS:

> Group 1: **HAM**
>  *Ham*BuRGeR (food)
>  *Ham*-FiSTeD (clumsy)
>  *Ham* aCToR (overacting performer)
>  *Ham* RaDio (amateur broadcasting)
>
>  Group 2: **HEY**
>  *Hey* JuDe (Beatles song)
>  *Hey* PReSTo (magician's cry)
>  *Hey*aWaKe (puzzle type)
>  *Hey*DaY (one's prime)
>
>  Group 3: **RE**
>  JuS iN *re* (legal term, a right in property ownership)
>  *Re*PoPuLaTe (fill again with people)
>  *Re*FiNaNCe (take out another loan)
>  *Re*:ZeRo ([Japanese short novel series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re:Zero_%E2%88%92_Starting_Life_in_Another_World)) *(solved by @JS1)*
>
>  Group 4: **The suffix -ITE**
>  SoCiaL*ite* (posh party-goer)
>  MeTeoR*ite* (space rock)
>  MaGNeT*ite* (iron ore)
>  ReaGaN*ite* (supporter of Ronald Reagan)

*(Okay, I'll write normally!)* As for the 'thematic' final connection:

> This is *not* your typical connecting group using the link-words as they are! Instead, in keeping with the puzzle's theme, let's now *remove the vowels* from the link-words! This gives us the following:
>
>  HAM --> HM,
>  HEY --> HY,
>  RE --> R, and
>  ITE --> T

Re-order these and put them together to find that the 'thematic one-word answer' is:

> **RHYTHM** - one of the longest words in English that can be made without any of the 5 vowels A, E, I, O or U!

Comment: The two groups you got are correct! As for the final answer, wait until you get all the groups ;)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @PilsNot3 - had a feeling I was onto something there; good to know for sure! And yes, time will tell, I guess...!

Comment: To pair with RYRPGEVP, perhaps ZnTArG and FPnYr?

Comment: May I suggest this: rot13(Er:Mreb), [which is this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re:Zero_%E2%88%92_Starting_Life_in_Another_World), making the final 4 be this: rot13(zbgbevmr, zntargvmr, fbpvnyvmr, betnavmr), possibly giving rot13(Mrnynaq).

Comment: @JS1 That looks like a solid possibility... Have to be honest, I've never heard of that one before. I can't think of a more fitting option right now - will edit and see how it goes... Thanks :)

Comment: Ooh, this is so close! The last category fits perfectly, but it wasn't the one I want @JS1 sorry :( Also, the final word is much more thematic than that; in fact, you don't even need to find a connection to figure it out!

Comment: @PilsNot3 OH! I've just seen what the final thematic word is! Now to work out how to get the one letter I'm missing from the rest...

Comment: @PilsNot3 Done! A nice solution - good puzzle! Got to be honest, I do love the solution method I came up with in Edit 6 as well - obviously the final word I settled on there definitely isn't as fitting as yours, but still: was a lot of fun to solve, thanks :)

Comment: @PilsNot3 Yeah, I found a few that would work for RGN - rot13(NENTBAVGR, BERTBAVGR, BETNAVGR naq ERNTNAVGR) are the others - but I figured the one I went for in the end is the most commonly well known and in general use of those, so would be the most accessible to everyone. (I'm guessing your one was the more politically themed of them?)

Answer (score 6):

**Partial** -  perhaps I am not very correct here, and I don't have any idea about the first box, but here it goes:

> [image]

Comment: +1 for the effort, but unfortunately not on the right track with the groups. You did get some of the words right, though, so keep trying. And remember that at the end you should be able to get a word that relates to the theme of the puzzle!

Comment: Parasite....might be an _organism_ rather than an _orgasm_.......

Comment: Yeah.. my mistake :P But it's a screenshot, and I don't have the original text anymore, so unable to edit it :(

Comment: Could the first one be "JSON"? The space could also indicate that it's actually two words.

Comment: @HugoZink Like I mentioned in the comments and the post, the phrase is spaced correctly. Looks like a lot of people are getting confused over it, so I’ll probably post a hint in a bit

Answer (score 0):

Just a partial answer with some potential solutions for the words (plus a couple added from comments below); too much to put in a comment, but not enough to be a complete wall. It feels like clue 1 is going to answer a lot of questions when we can figure it out.

**First row (1 - 4)**

> 1. [Jose / Joose / Jas], [One / Neo / Eon / Una / Uno / Oona / Neue], ?
>  2. Magenta / Magnet / Magneto / Magento
>  3. Week / Wake / Wok / Awoke / Woke / Wookie / Wiki / Wikia / Ewok / Weak
>  4. Argon / Regain / Oregon / Eragon / Region / Aragon / Oregano / Organ / Origin / Reign / Raygun / Regina / Uruguayan

**Second row (5 - 8)**

> 5. Meter (verb, distance, monitor) / Motor / Amateur / Mitre (bishop, joint, brand) / Mature
>  6. Zero / Azure / Azore / Ezra / Azera
>  7. Red / Redo / Erode / Rude / Radii / Ride / Road
>  8. Day / Dye / DIY

**Third row (9 - 12)**

> 9. Fasted / Feasted / OFSTED / Fisted
>  10. Scale / Scala / Social
>  11. Burger
>  12. Populate / Applet

**Fourth row (13 - 16)**

> 13. Fennec / Finance
>  14. Priest / Parasite / Prost / Poorest / Preset / Pursuit / Purest
>  15. Jade / Jed / Judo / Jedi
>  16. Actor / Cater

Comment: I got (4) reign, (7) road, (12) applet.

Comment: rot13(wbfhr bar, cevrfg, rmen, whqr) would refer to rot13(gur ovoyr)

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA why does rot13(cevrfg) fit that group, and why would rot13(wbfhr bar) be in Spanish when the others are in English?

Comment: @Joe: rot13(wbfhr bar) would match french also. Note that I just discovered the show, it does not air down here. And I forgot that this guy is spelt differently in english.